# How can I run a script on successful registration with extra field?

Tags: php, drupal-7, mailchimp

How can I run a script on successful registration with an extra field?
I have an extra field in my Drupal 7 registration form, called "city."
I have a PHP script that adds the user's email address to a mailchimp list with a $_GET; basically I just want to run the script with the field_city and email value with curl mailchimpscript.php?mail=email@email.com&city=(field_city)

Where can I run this once on registration, and pass both the email and field_city values?

Edit: there is no double-opt in, creates user and then gets logged in.